# Convert XML value to a table using SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

"I have a xml field with the following value:

```
<table>
  <id>{cdf8cafc-2b3c-454b-aab8-c6c27e96b675}</id>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="po_desc" value="Item-1" type="System.String" />
        <column name="Qty" value="15" type="System.Int32" />
        <column name="price" value="100" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="linetotal" value="1500" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="po_desc" value="" type="System.String" />
        <column name="Qty" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
        <column name="price" value="1" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="linetotal" value="1" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
</rows>
</table>
```

And I need to transform this to Row and columns as below

```
PO_desc    Qty    Price   LineTotal  
=====================================
item-1      15    100      1500
Item-2       1      1       1
=======================================
```

using MS SQL Query.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you looked at Openrowset?

Comment: Yep, OpenRowSet is the way to go, see this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-import-and-export-of-xml-documents-sql-server

Comment: @Harry, Why `OPENROWSET`, if there is explicitly stated *I have an xml field*?

Comment: @MB34 Same question as to Harry...

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @DummyTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXmlColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @DummyTable VALUES
('<table>
  <id>{cdf8cafc-2b3c-454b-aab8-c6c27e96b675}</id>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="po_desc" value="Item-1" type="System.String" />
        <column name="Qty" value="15" type="System.Int32" />
        <column name="price" value="100" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="linetotal" value="1500" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
    <row>
      <columns>
        <column name="po_desc" value="" type="System.String" />
        <column name="Qty" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
        <column name="price" value="1" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="linetotal" value="1" type="System.Decimal" />
        <column name="DefaultKey" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
      </columns>
    </row>
</rows>
</table>');
```

This is the query

```
SELECT r.value('(columns/column[@name="po_desc"]/@value)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PO_Desc
      ,r.value('(columns/column[@name="Qty"]/@value)[1]','int') AS Qty
      ,r.value('(columns/column[@name="price"]/@value)[1]','decimal') AS Price
      ,r.value('(columns/column[@name="linetotal"]/@value)[1]','decimal') AS LineTotal
FROM @DummyTable AS t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXmlColumn.nodes('/table/rows/row') AS A(r);
```